# LaTeX figure label from R plot using KnitR?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I can't get R/KnitR to create the LaTeX `\label{}` statement for a figure. The [manual](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) seems to indicate that a `\label{}` statement will be created by concatenating the string in fig.lp ("fig:" by default) with the label for the R-code chunk. I haven't been able to get this to work, however. No `\label{}` statement is created for the first figure created by knitting the MWE below. The second figure has it's label added with a workaround that I just discovered, putting the R chunk in a figure environment, and putting the `\label` tag after or inside the `\caption` tag.

```
\documentclass[12pt, english, oneside]{amsart}
\begin{document}

Figure \ref{fig:plot} doesn't have it's label.

<<plot>>=
plot(x=0, y=0)
@

Figure \ref{fig:plot2} has its label.

\begin{figure}
\caption{\label{fig:plot2}}
<<>>=
plot(x=1,y=1)
@
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Okay, I've found a workaround by putting the R chunk in a `\begin{figure} . . .\end{figure}` environment in LaTeX. I can create the label in that same environment. Still, I'd like to understand how Yihui intends for this to be handled with KnitR.

Comment: Have you tried `<<plot>>=` instead of `<<plot, fig.lp="fig:">>=` ?

Comment: I actually tried <<plot>>= first, just forgot to correct it in the MWE. Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can also include your custom label by putting the `\label{mylabel}` directly into the KnitR `fig.cap` chunk option. It should then dump that into the output. But you may have to beware of *escaping* the `\ ` character by using something like this: `<<plot, fig.cap="My caption text.\\label{mylabel}">>=`. I can't test, but if it works, you're welcome to repost as a solution.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to set `fig.cap = ''` (or whatever you wish) to ensure that a figure environment is used in the `latex` document. (you may have noticed that the `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` is missing along with the `\label{}` component

eg

```
\documentclass[12pt, english, oneside]{amsart}
\begin{document}
See Figure \ref{fig:plot}.
<<plot, fig.lp="fig:", fig.cap = ''>>=
plot(x=0, y=0)
@
\end{document}
```

I would agree that the [description from the website](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) is less than clear as to this being necessary.

> - fig.env: ('figure') the LaTeX environment for figures, e.g. set fig.env='marginfigure' to get \begin{marginfigure}
> - fig.cap: (NULL; character) figure caption to be used in a figure environment in LaTeX (in \caption{}); if NULL or NA, it will be
>     ignored, otherwise a figure environment will be used for the plots in
>     the chunk (output in \begin{figure} and \end{figure})

Although the [graphics manual is clear](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/), and the reasoning makes sense

> ### Figure Caption
>
> If the chunk option fig.cap is not NULL or NA, the
>   plots will be put in a figure environment when the output format is
>   LATEX, and this option is used to write a caption in this environment
>   using \caption{}. The other two related options are fig.scap and
>   fig.lp which set the short caption and a prefix string for the figure
>   label. The default short caption is extracted from the caption by
>   truncating it at the first period or colon or semi-colon. The label is
>   a combination of fig.lp and the chunk label. Because figure is a float
>   environment, it can float away from the chunk output to other places
>   such as the top or bottom of a page when the TEX document is compiled.

If you were wishing to replicate a `R` session output, you wouldn't want the figures to float away from the line of code which defines how they were created.