# Is it possible to give a figure/plot a label in Sweave?

Tags: r, latex, sweave

Given the following line of code:

```
<<myrcodeplot, fig.pos="H", fig.height=4, fig.width=4, fig.cap="Example of a plot">>=
```

I would like to give the plot that is generated here a label, so that I can simply refer to the plot as such in my LaTeX document:

```
\ref{plot}
```

Comment: If you are using `knitr`, rather than Sweave, then maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991735/latex-figure-label-from-r-plot-using-knitr) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926623/figures-captions-and-labels-in-knitr).

Comment: @lmo: Thank you, the first link you referred to used the `fig.lp="fig:"` argument which solved my problem.